# ReactJS: How to pass keycode to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is an input field and another component. I need to get the event keyCode to the second component.

I don't get both components connected as some posts said `ref` is not the best attempt for this. I don't really understand that...

**Parent**

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render () {
    return(
      <Input onKeyDown={() => { console.log('triggered keydown') }} />
      <Child />
    )
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
class Child extends Component {
  handleKeyDown (e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode) // <- Get Keycode from parent triggered keydown event
  }
  render () {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setState()` to update the current `keyCode` in state, and pass it to the child via prop.

In the child you can use the prop directly or process it in `componentWillReceiveProps()`, and set the result to the state.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {};
  }

  onKeyDown = (e) => this.setState({ keyCode: e.keyCode });

  render() {
    const { keyCode } = this.state;
  
    return (
      <div>
        <input onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown} />
      
        <Child keyCode={keyCode} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      doubleKeyCode: []
    };
  }
  
  handleKeyDown = (keyCode = 0) => this.setState((prevState) => ({
    doubleKeyCode: [...prevState.doubleKeyCode, keyCode * 2]
  }));
  
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.handleKeyDown(nextProps.keyCode);
  }

  render () {
    const { doubleKeyCode } = this.state;
    
    console.log(`render: ${doubleKeyCode}`);
    
    return (
      <div>{doubleKeyCode.join(', ')}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: But will it fire if you press the same key multiple times? Then the state won't change

Comment: I'm using a component, so the component will rerender on each key press (see updated example). Do you want it to render, or you want to avoid it? If you want to avoid it, you can use PureComponent.

Comment: If I press the arrow down key twice, I need to get `38` twice. But right now I just get it once. I'm also using components...

Comment: yes, I want to process number after number in a own function inside of a component. So a `console.log()` would show me 38, 38, 38, but `componentWillReceiveProps` will only handle 38 once.

Comment: The state can be an array.